# How can I access to the same post-type “page” from multiple different urls?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm developing a Wordpress website, and I have a problem with permalinks.

I need to deal with following situations:

- http://domain/center1/ -> rewrite to "template_home_page" ( which has a different permalink)
- http://domain/center1/students -> rewrite to "template_students_page" ( which has a different permalink) ...
- http://domain/center2/ -> rewrite to "template_home_page" ( which has a different permalink)
- http://domain/center2/students -> rewrite to "template_students_page" ( which has a different permalink)

I think that's possible with add_rewrite_url and add_rewrite_tags , but I don't know how.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: did you mean you want the page eg `http://domain/center1/` to be `http://domain/template_home_page/ `?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the one page to another page then it is possible with the .htaccess file, add the below rule in the .htaccess:

Redirect 301 http://domain/center1/ https://example.com/sample-page

Don't forget to change the example URL. You will able to add multiple redirects rule in .htaccess file, according to your need.